# Docker build command hangs in Google Cloud Shell without any message

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to build a Springboot webapp docker image in Google Cloud Shell. But the **build command hangs without any message in the terminal**. Please help.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD target/inventory-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
CMD java -jar app.jar
```

**Build command hanging in Google Cloud Shell:**

[image: Docker build command hanging in the Google Cloud Shell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the image got built after a long time. But just wondering why it took more than 15 mins for just downloading 17.6 MB base image. Anyway the issue got resolved just by taking more time.